# How do I configure reconnect logic for SignalR within an angular 8 project?

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript, signalr

I'm using

```
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
```

in Angular 8 project.

Unfortunately it appears the documentation is out of date?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1

The documentation claims there is a method

```
withAutomaticReconnect()
```

to be used as

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/chatHub")
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .build();
```

However, when I attempt to enter this in I get

> Property 'WithAutomaticReconnect' does not exist on type 'HubConnectionBuilder'

Is this a documentation out of date issue? Or am I misunderstanding the configuration?

Here is my exact code BEFORE trying to add this method

```
    private _hubConnection: HubConnection;
```

...

```
        this._hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(this.myAPIUrl + '/myHub', { accessTokenFactory: () => tokenFromCache })
        .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Error)
        .build();
```

Comment: In the new signalr (.net core) there is no ```.withAutomaticReconnect()``` method since it is for old signalr (.net fw). What you need to do is do your custom reconnect logic.

Comment: @aspnet/signalr is the super old version it has been succeeded by @microsoft/signalr - please use this one

Answer (score 9):

The documentation you reference uses npm package "@microsoft/signalr" whereas yours uses "@aspnet/signalr"

Comment: good point. I think this might be better suited as a comment though? What do you think?

Comment: Just to note, this packages differs on documentation site based on .net core version - look https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @aspnet/signalr is the super old version it has been succeeded by @microsoft/signalr

Answer (score 5):

you need a more up to date version, I believe it is version 3, just run the following command inn your terminal I am using it with a react front end.

```
npm install @microsoft/signalr
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do like this

```
this._hubConnection.start().catch(_ => setTimeout(() => {
            this._hubConnection.start();
        }, 1000));
```

So if there any exception it will reconnect your client to the hub